# cmake osx deployment target is '10.11' but CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT error

Tags: python, macos, cmake

I'm getting this cmake error while installing a python file related to openAI gym. The error log which is bugging me is the below lines..

```
CMake Error at     /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.5.2/share/cmake/Modules/Platform/Darwin.cmake:76    (message):
 CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is '10.11' but CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT:

 ""

is not set to a MacOSX SDK with a recognized version.  Either set
CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT to a valid SDK or set CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to
empty.
```

Can anyone please guide me how to overcome this error ? I have also attached the full error log if it helps. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qxyxaleu38xgwi0/errorLogOpenAI.txt?dl=0

I have tried set CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET empty command and re-executed installation, but it still threw same error.

Complete error log : https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0dftar6ovbrreu/pachi_2_pdf.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Try setting it to "macosx10.11" or "macosx10.10" and make sure you run cmake again. If not then run "xcodebuild -version -sdk macosx10.10 Path" and update the path

Comment: I dont understand this 'xcrun make' error after updating the path. When i try to install now it fails with the below xcrun make error. Commands as follows.

  ~ xcodebuild -version -sdk macosx10.12 Path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk
➜  ~ xcrun make
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/path/to/Mac10.12SDK" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "make", not a developer tool or in PATH
~
And xcode sdk gives the following sdk version.
macOS SDKs:
 macOS 10.12                    -sdk macosx10.12

Comment: I have also tried setting with export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.12 command. And this command, export SDKROOT=/path/to/Mac10.12SDK.

Comment: My OS is El Capitan 10.11.6 and in the xcodebuild show sdks gives macOS sdk to be 10.12. Is that causing a glitch ?

Comment: Yeah, I got returned with this. bash-3.2$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates. When I ran xcode 8 after Mac Sierra upgrade it ran and installed few components too.

Comment: You can try removing value of CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET. Set this `set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET  "")`

Comment: Hmm, I get this log when i gave the above command.. I googled it out, but i couldn't find why.
bash-3.2$ set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "")
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'

Comment: Full log details which i tried: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0dftar6ovbrreu/pachi_2_pdf.pdf?dl=0

Comment: My bad, you should try calling `unset(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)` instead of `set(CMAKE...)`

Comment: Thanks for responding. unset CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET command alone without any additional export CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer‌​/Platforms/MacOSX.pl‌​atform/Developer/SDK‌​s/MacOSX10.12.sdk cleared me this issue. If you could post what u have suggest as answer I would mark that as answer and close this. Thank you @NulledPointer

Comment: expanded it to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on comment. As error text suggests:

```
is not set to a MacOSX SDK with a recognized version.  Either set
CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT to a valid SDK or set CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to
empty.
```

You can unset CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to let cmake chose  defaults. You can add following in your cmake file:

```
unset(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)
```